# Counting number of specific strings in an R data frame

Tags: r, string, dataframe, count, unique

I have a data frame that has many columns, but the two columns I am interested in are major and department.  I need to find a way to count the number of specific entries in a column.  So my data frame looks something like

```
student_num    major          dept
123            child          education
124            child          education
125            special        education
126            justice        administration
127            justice        administration
128            justice        administration
129            police         administration
130            police         administration
```

What I want is a student count for each major and department.  Something like

```
education   child   special    administration    justice    police
3           2       1          5                 3          2
```

I have tried several methods but nothing is quite what I need.  I tried using the aggregate() function and the ddply() from plyr but they give me department as two - for two unique entries, education and administration.  How can I count each unique entry and not how many unique entries there are?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try:

```
library(dplyr)
count(my_dataframe, major)
count(my_dataframe, dept)
```

Comment: This is almost too simple.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
# Create example data frame
dt <- read.table(text = "student_num    major          dept
123            child          education
                 124            child          education
                 125            special        education
                 126            justice        administration
                 127            justice        administration
                 128            justice        administration
                 129            police         administration
                 130            police         administration",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Select columns
dt <- dt[, c("major", "dept")]

# Unlist the data frame
dt_vec <- unlist(dt)

# Count the number
table(dt_vec)

dt_vec
administration          child      education        justice         police 
             5              2              3              3              2 
       special 
             1
```